# Pandas deep copy a row from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with few rows. I want to create a row on top of the first row and do some data manipulation on that first row. For example, let's say the dataframe looks like this

```
EId      Details
  1     {'Age':24,'Occupation':'Engineer'}
  2     {'Age':26,'Occupation':'Tester'}
```

I want to create another row on top of the first row and modify some data for that row. 
I understand that copying a row doesn't recursively copy the python objects (which means if I modify Age for the new row, the original row in the dataframe also gets modified). So I tried deepCopy. It worked with pandas 0.19.2 but not with 0.23.4.

This is what I tried

```
new_row_df=df.head(1).copy(deep=True)
new_row_df['Details']=copy.deepcopy((df.head(1))['file_columns'])
```

Even after that change, it still copied the reference. When I modify 'Details' column in the copied row, the original row also got modified.

Then I thought changing to dictionary and modifying should work. So I tried this.

```
new_row = df.head(1).to_dict('list')
```

Even after I converted to dictionary and modified the values, still the original row got modified. 
The other way I can do is use json.dumps. But want to ask the community is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Deepcopying does not work on mutable python objects inside columns. You will have to manually iterate and call `[item.copy() for item in df['Details']]`

Comment: Thank you coldspeed for the solution. Sorry I did not check that post previously. Thanks again.